# No suggest with codeception in IntelliJ 2019.1

Tags: php, intellij-idea, codeception

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.1 with PHP Plugin v191.6183.95 and Codeception Plugin v191.5849.22 on Windows 10. I configured it to use PHP language level 7.1 with CLI interpreter PHP 7.1.4. Use Codeception version 2.5.5.

I installed codeception using composer but since using that executable didn't work, I also downloaded codeception.phar. With that I was able to execute `php vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` and `php vendor/bin/codecept generate:suite api` to setup an API testing project.

When I started writing tests, IntelliJ doesn't suggest functions for that "$I" object:

```
<?php 

class GetUserInfoCest
{
    public function _before(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(ApiTester $I)
    {
    }

    public function getUserInfoViaAPI(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $I->haveHttpHeader();
    }
}
```

When I climb up dependency tree using Ctrl->left_click I don't see those functions anywhere.

How can I make IntelliJ suggest functions?

### Update 1

Now it works, I had to add both parameters.

```
$I->haveHttpHeader('Cookie', 'mein_muenchen_backend_session=XXXXXXXX');
$I->sendGET('/api/v1/lists/login/userinfo');
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
```

What I don't understand, though, is how I use PhpBrowser (https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) functions there. For example, I used `$I->setCookie(..., ...)` but Codeception said `Call to undefined method ApiTester::setCookie`

### Update 2

I now understand, that I created a suite with REST enabled which uses PhpBrowser. But when I want to use different functions of PhpBrowser, I also have to enable it in suite's yml file

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: https://<API's URL>/
            depends: PhpBrowser
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: https://<OAuth login URL>/
```

Comment: I just realized it works when I add both parameters for `haveHttpHeader`.

Comment: You must execute `codecept build` or `codecept run` first to generate some support files providing those methods.

Comment: Yeah, I tried running my test and perhaps after that it found that function. Thanks @Naktibalda